# Getting GPS location in Android

Tags: android, gps, android-permissions

I am trying to get the current GPS-Location via Android, but it doesn't work and shows error. I have also included the `runtime permission` required but it still doesn't work.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

    }



}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double latitude=location.getLatitude();
    double longitude=location.getLongitude();

    Log.i("Geo_location","Latitude: "+latitude+" ,Longitude: "+longitude);
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}
```

}

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.shaloin.gps">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

The error is: 
 `"gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.`
 for which I have added the runtime permission as stated in this link [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). Please help. Thank you :)

Comment: You are not requesting `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` in the manifest. Hence, get rid of the `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` code from Java. [Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Location/Classic) demonstrating using `LocationManager` with runtime permissions.

Comment: @CommonsWare  I did as you asked me , but it still shows error `"gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not requesting run time permissions correctly.

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // TODO: Consider calling
    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
    //                                          int[] grantResults)
    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

}
```

Here you are explicitly requesting a location update when the permission IS NOT granted. What you should do however in the if condition is that if the permission is not granted, request permission.

To fix this, cut the line of the locationManager.requestLocationUpdates and paste it outside of the curly brackets.

Then inside the if condition, check for the SDK version, and if it is higher than 23, request the permission.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) { // Marshmallow

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
return;
```

Finally you need to create a method that will override "onRequestPermissionsResult".
Creating a method must be done outside of the onCreate method.

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    if (requestCode == LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {

        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // start to find location...

        } else { // if permission is not granted

            // decide what you want to do if you don't get permissions
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, you need to identify a unique final int variable for each permission, in order to request permissions according to variable value. This is done in the beginning of the class, where you define your instance variables.

```
final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1252; //Note that the value 1252 is arbitrary.
```

Comment: As you have said I have cut `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);` and pasted it outside the curly brackets , what should I do inside the `if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){` statement

Comment: @PritomMazumdar well, you can make a copy of 
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_P‌​ROVIDER, 0, 0, this); 
there, so that way when the permission is granted, the gps will update the location.
And in the else you can just return an alert dialog or something. 
Basically you can do whatever you want to do depending on whether or not the user gave you permission.

Comment: If I copy `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);` inside `if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){` statement, then again I have to add `permission` because as soon as I add the line inside `if` statement I get a red colored underline stating that I have to add permission `Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with checkPermission) or explicitly handle a potential SecurityException`

Comment: @PritomMazumdar oops. My bad. Just leave it blank, or you can log something for debugging purposes like "Permission granted".

Comment: Thank you, I have got rid of the errors, but just one more help, how do I display the latitude and longitude? I wanted to display a `Toast` message but I am not able to figure out as to where should I place the `Toast`. Can you please help me?

Comment: Firstly you can make an instance variable of type Location called location.
Then in the onCreate method after you requestLocationUpdates, you can initialize the location variable that you defined earlier `location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);` then call `onLocationChanged(location);`. You can make the Toast message in the onLocationChanged method, however keep in mind that every time the gps will detect movement, a toast will appear. So depending on the usage that you want, place it accordingly.

Comment: @PritomMazumdar I think that I have answered your question, so you should mark it as solved.